# WIndows 7: would like recursively check a directory for changes to files and folders since my last visit - not in realtime or by monitoring

Tags: windows, monitoring

I have found varieties of this question.  Most of them fall under monitoring and others are said to be buggy.  A continuously monitoring program won't help me and neither will a list of the most recently modified files.

I would like to check if the directory, its sub folders and files have changed since my last visit.  It seems to me that I'd likely need a program that maintains and index of that directory and compares it with its condition when I tell it to.  Then that program could output to a log for my use.

This is on Windows 7 over a shared network, the folder(s) I'd like to check have 4-50GB of data.

I did find this, however I am still learning how to program.  I think it describes what I want:

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0490.html

Thanks for considering.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to check any modification in your system, in your case the folders is to use a Checksum software to do this. There's a lot of them so I suggest you to try these ones:

[Nirsoft's HashMyFiles](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/hash_my_files.html)

[Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533)  (command line only)

or this utility more specific to folders

[Nirsoft's FolderChangesView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/folder_changes_view.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the Nirsoft programs don't work for me because I can't "monitor" the folder.  The only MD5 hashing utility I've found that takes a recursive hash of a directory is MD5summer: http://sourceforge.net/projects/md5summer/ . But it takes forever to calculate hashes on the 30,000 file directory I'm checking on from time to time.  Is there a faster way to do this that doesn't require constant monitoring?

Comment: May be this one: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/folder-monitor-notifies-you-of-changes-to-your-local-directories/

Comment: this is a nice program too, but it uses monitoring.  i need something i can check from time to time, not by constantly running